# How to print only specific name from the string in Python

Tags: python, string

This is my input string:

```
C:\Company\ProjectList\ProjectName\Requriment\..etc
```

I would like expected output string:

```
ProjectName
```

I want to print only project name from the string. Is this possible in Python?

Comment: You need to be more specific. What do you expect ProjectName to be? Is it always the 4th item in the string? Also, did you try anything yourself?

Comment: project name is always different,  i given here as a example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `os.sep` to split by a delimiter. The benefit of this method is if you move to a different system and your input paths change format, you will not need to modify your code.

Note that, as per your example, we want to access the 4th component in your path when splitting by `os.sep`. Since indexing begins at `0`, we index by `[3]`.

```
import os

x = r'C:\Company\ProjectList\ProjectName\Requriment'

res = x.split(os.sep)[3]

print(res)

ProjectName
```

Comment: All answers here are pretty much the same but this is the only one that is platform independent, I would just add a remark about `[3]` to explain that it's only true in this specific case, but OP never gave us anything else to work with anyway

Answer (score 2):

If you certainly know your project structure, split your text then print the part u want. In your case for ex: 
` C:\Company\ProjectList\ProjectName\Requriment\
This will print what you want:

```
raw = "Input String: C:\Company\ProjectList\ProjectName\Requriment\..etc"
name = raw.split("\\")[3]
```

If you don't know the structure for sure, I don't think there is a fast, pythonic way to extract project name. You must build a model for name recognition

Comment: Same as my answer but you got there first! - upvoted!

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the project name:

```
string = "C:\Company\ProjectList\ProjectName\Requriment\"

project_name = string.split("\\")[3]
```

This will only work if project name is always the fourth element.

Note that the back slash needs to be escaped with another backslash.

Comment: Do you know that your answer is the exact same as enamoria's answer

Comment: @U8-Forward - I only saw their answer after I submitted mine. What is the etiquette here? I can see they submitted 2 minutes before me. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: It depends on you

Comment: @U8-Forward - I have upvoted their answer. Hopefully this is acceptable. Mine is now bottom of the pile :)